# Mono: Return results from a long running method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, reactive-programming

Currently I'm beginnging with Spring + reactive programming. My aim is to return a result in a REST-endpoint from a long running method (polling on a database). I'm stuck on the api. I simply don't know how to return the result as `Mono` in my `FooService.findFoo` method.

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

  @Autowired
  private FooService fooService;

  @GetMapping("/foo/{id}")
  private Mono<ResponseEntity<Foo> findById(@PathVariable String id) {
    return fooService.findFoo(id).map(foo -> ResponseEntity.ok(foo)) //
      .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
  }
  ...
}

@Service
public class FooService {

  public Mono<Foo> findFoo(String id) {
    // this is the part where I'm stuck
    // I want to return the results of the pollOnDatabase-method
  }

  private Foo pollOnDatabase(String id) {
    // polling on database for a while
  }
}
```

Comment: Was this releated to my question? If so, I don't get it.

Comment: Yes. I mean from your service class findFoo method, cant you do like `return Mono.just(pollOnDatabase(id))`

Comment: Thanks a million, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: You are using a database, which means JDBC, which means you basically put lipstick on a pig. JDBC is blocking and not-reactive, so you are basically gaining nothing. You can achieve the same without reactive programming using an async result.

Comment: True on that. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Also using Mono.just() will block your calling thread. See answer from @szilárd-fodor

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Mono.fromSupplier` method! :)

```
@Service
public class FooService {

  public Mono<Foo> findFoo(String id) {
    return Mono
      .fromSupplier(() -> pollOnDatabase(id))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
  }

  private Foo pollOnDatabase(String id) {
    // polling on database for a while
  }
}
```

With this method we return a Mono value ASAP, constant time with a supplier which will be evaluated on demand by the caller's subscribe. This is the non blocking way to call a long-running-blocking method.

**BE AWARE** that without subscription on `boundedElastic` the blocking `pollOnDatabase` method will block the original thread, which leads to *thread starvation*. You can find different schedules for every kind of tasks [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html).

**DO NOT** use `Mono.just` with long-running calculations as it will run the calculation before returning the `Mono` instance, thereby blocking the given thread.

**+1**: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCu73WVg8Ps) video to learn to avoid "reactor meltdown". Use some [lib](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) to detect blocking calls from non-blocking threads.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You could just do

```
@Service
public class FooService {

  public Mono<Foo> findFoo(String id) {
    return Mono.just(pollOnDatabase(id));
  }

  private Foo pollOnDatabase(String id) {
    // polling on database for a while
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution would evaluate the `pollOnDatabase` function first, then would give the result to the `Mono.just` function, and just after that the `findFoo` function could return. So to create and return a reactive instance we would block the main thread with the long running database call.